# How to extract value from array js

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I've already built a table with DOM methods, taking in input the number of row and column. Now I need to take the number of row and column by the element of the array `myBooks` and put in my table the values of the same array. How should I do?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>tabella dom</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="tabellaDom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="numeri">
 Inserisci due valori: <br>
 <input name="valore1">
 <input name="valore2">
 <br>
 <input type="button" name="creaTabella" value="Crea Tabella" onclick="creaTable(numeri.valore1.value, numeri.valore2.value);">
 <br>

 <div id="myDynamicTable"></div> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function creaTable(a, b) {
  var tableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.setAttribute("id", "tabella");
  var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
  tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
  tbl.border = '1';

  for (var j = 0; j < a; j++) {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    console.log('tr.value');
    tbdy.appendChild(tr);
    const btnDelete = document.createElement('input');
    btnDelete.setAttribute("type", "button");
    btnDelete.setAttribute("value", "-");
    tr.appendChild(btnDelete);

    btnDelete.onclick = function() {
      tr.remove();
    };

    for (var k = 0; k < b; k++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.width = '75';
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cella " + j + "," + k));
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }
  tableDiv.appendChild(tbl);
}
```

```js
var myBooks = [{
    "Book ID": "1",
    "Book Name": "Computer Architecture",
    "Category": "Computers",
    "Price": "125.60"
  },
  {
    "Book ID": "2",
    "Book Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book",
    "Category": "Programming",
    "Price": "56.00"
  },
  {
    "Book ID": "3",
    "Book Name": "Popular Science",
    "Category": "Science",
    "Price": "210.40"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: no please, I'm learning javascript

Comment: Ah, alright. Just asked. `:)`

Comment: Can you use Ctrl + M and add more code - HTML and CSS too, if you have, please? Make it a working [mcve].

Comment: I've edited the post, hope it's ok now

Answer (score 0):

```
  var data="";
  b--;
  if(b==0){
   data=myBooks[a-1]['Book ID'];
  }
  else if(b==1){
   data=myBooks[a-1]['Book Name'];
  }
  else if(b==2){
   data=myBooks[a-1]['Category'];
  }
  else if(b==3){
   data=myBooks[a-1]['Price'];
  }
```

Try this code. Here a is number of row and b is number of column